# Select rows from database where the value in one column is distinct and limit to 5 latest

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I have a database of images, the image rows are updated with the last IP of who viewed them and updates a date_updated column with the current timestamp. I am trying to get the last 5 images viewed but only each distinct ip address, I don't want one person to flood the last viewed result.

**Fiddle:**:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5b05/16

**Desired result:**
The desired result while selecting from this data set:

```
SELECT * FROM `image` ORDER BY `date_updated` DESC;

|   IMAGE | WIDTH | HEIGHT | DATE_ADDED | DATE_UPDATED | UPDATED_BY_IP |
|---------|-------|--------|------------|--------------|---------------|
| 1x1XGY4 |  1920 |   1080 | 1417546414 |   1421712314 |   192.168.0.7 |
| 1x1XGY3 |  1920 |   1080 | 1417546413 |   1421712313 |   192.168.0.7 |
| 1x1XGY2 |  1920 |   1080 | 1417546412 |   1421712312 |  192.168.0.10 |
| 1x1XGY1 |  1920 |   1080 | 1417546411 |   1421712311 |  192.168.0.10 |
| 1oApS54 |  1920 |   1080 | 1417138874 |   1421685474 |   192.168.0.2 |
| 1oApS53 |  1920 |   1080 | 1417138873 |   1421685473 |   192.168.0.2 |
| 1oApS52 |  1920 |   1080 | 1417138872 |   1421685472 |  192.168.0.10 |
| 1oApS51 |  1920 |   1080 | 1417138871 |   1421685471 |  192.168.0.10 |
| 1ydhtQ4 |  1920 |   1080 | 1421460434 |   1421685154 |   192.168.0.6 |
| 1ydhtQ3 |  1920 |   1080 | 1421460433 |   1421685153 |   192.168.0.7 |
| 1ydhtQ2 |  1920 |   1080 | 1421460432 |   1421685152 |  192.168.0.10 |
| 1ydhtQ1 |  1920 |   1080 | 1421460431 |   1421685151 |   192.168.0.5 |
| 1WyQib4 |  1920 |   1080 | 1420869354 |   1421634384 |   192.168.0.8 |
| 1WyQib3 |  1920 |   1080 | 1420869353 |   1421634383 |   192.168.0.2 |
| 1WyQib2 |  1920 |   1080 | 1420869352 |   1421634382 |   192.168.0.3 |
| 1WyQib1 |  1920 |   1080 | 1420869351 |   1421634381 |  192.168.0.10 |
| 1izDqg4 |  1920 |   1080 | 1416948144 |   1421608564 |   192.168.0.2 |
| 1izDqg3 |  1920 |   1080 | 1416948143 |   1421608563 |   192.168.0.2 |
| 1izDqg2 |  1920 |   1080 | 1416948142 |   1421608562 |   192.168.0.5 |
| 1izDqg1 |  1920 |   1080 | 1416948141 |   1421608561 |  192.168.0.10 |
```

With pseudo select statement:

> SELECT * FROM image *WHERE updated_by_ip IS DISTINCT* ORDER BY
>   date_updated DESC LIMIT 5

```
|   IMAGE | WIDTH | HEIGHT | DATE_ADDED | DATE_UPDATED | UPDATED_BY_IP |
|---------|-------|--------|------------|--------------|---------------|
| 1x1XGY4 |  1920 |   1080 | 1417546414 |   1421712314 |   192.168.0.7 |
| 1x1XGY2 |  1920 |   1080 | 1417546412 |   1421712312 |  192.168.0.10 |
| 1oApS54 |  1920 |   1080 | 1417138874 |   1421685474 |   192.168.0.2 |
| 1ydhtQ4 |  1920 |   1080 | 1421460434 |   1421685154 |   192.168.0.6 |
| 1ydhtQ1 |  1920 |   1080 | 1421460431 |   1421685151 |   192.168.0.5 |
```

**Closet result:**

The best I could come up with is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT updated_by_ip, MAX(date_updated) AS date_updated 
FROM `image` GROUP BY updated_by_ip ORDER BY date_updated DESC LIMIT 5;
```

This gives me:

```
| UPDATED_BY_IP | DATE_UPDATED |
|---------------|--------------|
|   192.168.0.7 |   1421712314 |
|  192.168.0.10 |   1421712312 |
|   192.168.0.2 |   1421685474 |
|   192.168.0.6 |   1421685154 |
|   192.168.0.5 |   1421685151 |
```

Of which I could do a

```
while (SELECT DISTINCT updated_by_ip ...)
{
    $result_rows[] = SELECT * FROM image 
                    WHERE updated_by_ip = query[updated_by_ip] 
                    AND date_updated = query[date_updated] LIMIT 1
}
```

However, was hoping to find a way to do this without having to do a bunch of post processing and additional queries, as well, selecting by updated_by_ip and date_updated doesn't seem very stable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this without the MySQL GROUP BY extension, you can try this:

First, obtain the most recent update time from five distinct IP numbers, with this subquery.

```
     SELECT updated_by_ip, MAX(date_updated) as date_updated
       FROM image  
      GROUP BY updated_by_ip
      ORDER BY 2 DESC
      LIMIT 5
```

If your table is big, an index on `(updated_by_ip, date_updated)` will help performance.

Then, join that to the main query to that subquery to get your result.

```
SELECT i.*
  FROM image i
  JOIN (
         SELECT updated_by_ip, MAX(date_updated) as date_updated
           FROM image  
          GROUP BY updated_by_ip
          ORDER BY 2 DESC
          LIMIT 5
        ) m USING(updated_by_ip, date_updated)
ORDER BY i.date_updated DESC
```

See this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5b05/21/0

Answer (score 0):

It's not the prettiest query (incorrect according to the SQL standard) but it works in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `image`
GROUP BY updated_by_ip
ORDER BY `date_updated` DESC
```

In Postgres you would use `DISTINCT ON(...)` but MySQL doesn't support that so just grouping by the columns you want to have distinct is the easiest workaround. The alternative is using subqueries but that performs quite a bit less optimal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this does not return the latest image viewed for a particular IP, grouping returns an arbitrary row for each IP result.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use variables to enumerate the rows:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM (SELECT i.*,
             (@rn := if(@uip = updated_by_ip, @rn + 1,
                        if(@uip := updated_by_ip, 1, 1)
                       )
             )
      FROM image i CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @uip := '', @rn := 0) vars
      WHERE updated_by_ip 
      ORDER BY updated_by_ip, date_updated DESC
     ) i
WHERE seqnum <= 5;
```